# Maquetar email con imágenes para Outlook

Tags: email, diseño

Estoy maquetando un email pero tengo varios problemas para el cliente de correos Outlook que no me redimensiona las imagenes y no me pilla algunos estilos en linea.

```
<tr style="background-color: #fff;">
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td width="80px" height="80px" colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
        <img width="80px" height="80px" style="border-radius: 40px; padding-right: 8px;" src="${signature.imageUrl}" alt="imageProfile">
    </td>
    <td colspan="6">
        <p style="text-align: left; padding-left: 8px;">
            <b> ${signature.name} </b><br>
            ${signature.duty}<br>
            ${signature.department}<br>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

No se si es posible redimensionar imagenes para Outlook o las imagenes deben tener el tamaño deseado en el momento de generar la plantilla.

Comment: prueba con `width="80"` sin `px`, y cuales estilos no te capta?

Comment: @Roy funciona, gracias! por lo demás voy bien.

Comment: genial, saludos @charli